# How to remove items from the list in case of minimum size condition is present in Java 8?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I want to remove an items from the list only in case if it is not the last one in the collection.

For example:

```
List<String> items = ....
Iterator<String> it = items.iterator();
while (it.hasNext() && items.size() > 1) {
String item = it.next();
   if (condition(item)) {
     it.remove();
   }
}
```

Is it possible to do the same in a more elegant way by using streams in Java 8 ?

Comment: Do you mean remove all elements in a collection *except* the last one?

Comment: @NicholasK, yeap that's what I mean

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you need to remove elements based on a condition, unless it is the last item in the list you could utilize [`removeIf()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#removeIf-java.util.function.Predicate-) which:

> Removes all of the elements of this collection that satisfy the given predicate.

Where the given predicate is that the item satisfies the condition. However you will need to first make sure that not all of the items will be removed by `removeIf()` (Which would result in removing every element in the list). You can use [`sublist()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#subList(int,%20int)) to remove all but the last element if all would be removed:

```
//If all the elements would be removed, use sublist to get every element but last one
//Clear sublist
if(items.stream().allMatch(e -> condition(e))) {
    items.subList(0, items.size() -1).clear();
} else {
    //else it is safe to directly call removeIf()
    items.removeIf(e -> condition(e));
}
```

Or to ensure that `condition(e)` is only checked once, you can do:

```
items.subList(0, items.size() -1).removeIf(e -> condition(e)); 
if(items.size() > 1 && condition(items.get(items.size()-1))) {
     items.remove(items.size()-1);
}
```

(Thanks @Holger for the suggestion)

Comment: Thank's mate! That is exactly what I need.

Comment: @YCF_L Finally edited. After looking at your solution I'm a bit confused whether the OP wants to remove it unless it is at the last position, or if OP wants to remove it unless it would be the last element in the list

Comment: Learn the power of `subList`. Instead of `String temp = items.get(items.size() -1); items.clear(); items.add(temp);`, you can use `items.subList(0, items.size() -1).clear();` Or you replace the entire operation with `items.subList(0, items.size() -1).removeIf(e -> condition(e)); if(items.size() > 1 && condition(items.get(items.size()-1))) items.remove(items.size()-1);`, which avoids checking `condition` multiple times (all assuming that the list is not initially empty; otherwise that has to be checked).

Comment: @Holger That is genius. Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

You can get the last item of the List and filter when is the last element and the condition is not satisfied.

```
I lastItem = items.get(items.size() - 1);
List<I> result = items.stream().filter( item -> item.equals(lastElement) || !condition(item)).collect(Collectors.toList());
```